# Loop and display confusion

Tags: java

I apologize if this seems like a simple question, but I have a problem I'm trying to solve and haven't quite gotten my head around how to display to results properly. So basically its asking to accept user input for a car traveling a certain distance. So I used a scanner object to get the time (in hrs) as well as the speed(mps). so to get the distance you simply multiply these 2 values. But my problem is in the display, I used a for loop to display how much distance the user traveled for every hour (starting from 1 - until it has reached the time the user inputs) the for loop looks like this:

```
    // Calculate and display distance traveled
    distance = speed * time;
    System.out.println("Hour Distance Traveled");
    System.out.println("--------------------------");

    for (time =1; time <= distance/speed; time++)
    {
             System.out.println(time + "\t" + distance);
    }
```

So I'm obviously stuck on how to display the distance in incremented form, like how time is displayed, I'm not sure how to go about it, and more importantly if a for loop is the appropriate loop to use in this case. I'm not asking to get the problem done for me but I would appreciate any advice or explanation on how to go about solving it or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop you want to multiply the time ( in current iteration ) by the speed, not to use the final calculated distance.

So:

```
System.out.println("" + time + "\t" + ( time * speed ) );
```

Should work for you.

**EDIT** Elaborating a little to answer the comment

You perform the same task twice. Once when calculating the result and one for tracing. You can connect the two and this way show the progress as it is calculated. Of course, if you don't need to print anything, you can just perform the multiplication as you did...

```
/* time and speed received from user. */
/* initialize distance */
distance = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= time; i++)
{
    /* increment distance in each iteration */
    distance += speed;
    /* print as you progress */
    System.out.println(i + "\t" + distance);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, but something still seems off in the way I wrote the for loop. I initialized distance after getting the user input, and then I used it as part of test expression for the for loop, 'distance/speed', then it's technically used again in the println statement within the body of the loop. I'm not very experienced but this just seems a bit redudent, yet it works. Can you explain a this, also, I would like to know If I made adequate use of this loop for this problem.

Comment: It does look redundant, but I tend not to change the whole code in a post, so I can focus the problem itself. I will add a further example to a way I would write that, and hope it will help.

Comment: Ok, so basically the calculation is done in terms of adding the speed by itself after each iteration, until the test expression is proving false(which is basically multiplication). Great, thanks. One thing though, the test expression should be 'i <= time', when I ran it using 'i < time', the program stops one hour before the hour entered by the user.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a typo... fixed

Answer (score 1):

> I used a scanner object to get the time (in hrs) as well as the
>   speed(mps).

Well, If i understood you correctly, this is probably what you want:

```
for (time =1; time <= inputTime; time++)
    {
            distance = inputSpeed * time;
             System.out.println(time + "\t" + distance);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (time =1; time <= endTime; time++)
{
         distance = speed * time;
         System.out.println(time + "\t" + distance);
}
```

you just need to update the distance in the loop

Comment: this won't work because you're changing distance even though you use it as a condition in your for loop. You're partially right though.

Comment: yep you are right I just copied the loop as it was by mistake:P now it should be fine:)

Answer (score 0):

You're running into confusion because you're trying to reuse the same variables "time" and "distance" for two different things in the same block of code - both for the entire trip, and also for each hour block.  Use different variable names, and it becomes so much easier.

So, you read "time" and "distance" for a journey - so that's "tripHours" and "tripDistance".

In your loop, you're counting up the hours, so you could have something like :

```
int tripDistance = speed * tripHours;
for (int hour = 1; hour <= tripHours; hour++)
    int distance = hour * speed;
```

Comment: The reason I didn't create to additional variables for time and speed is because for some reason I think the less variables I create/use the cleaner(elegant?) the code looks, I feel its a bit unnecessary to create many variables. yet I see how it makes the solving the problem easier. What is the ideal way to code, as far as using variables, less is better or use as much as one thinks one needs?

Comment: As much as one needs - EVERY TIME.  Every variable should capture just one concept, and be named to accordingly.  Storage and processing overhead are utterly negligible (the JVM's pretty good at looking after that side of things).  If at any stage you think you have too many variables flying around to keep track of, then that's a "code smell" that it's time to refactor (ie. split the method into smaller chunks), but don't reuse (possible exception of iterating variables like 'i', but even then better to use names like 'hour').